# How to check if an element exists in multiple lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
companies = ['apple','google','tesla','facebook','cisco']
list_1 = ['apple','google','tesla','facebook']
list_2 = ['google','tesla','facebook']
list_3 = ['apple','tesla','cisco']
list_4 = ['apple','google','tesla']
list_5 = ['google','tesla','facebook']
```

And I have pandas df as follows - 
`COMPANY_DF`

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+---------------+
|column1 |             column2                   |   column3     |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------|
|apple   | [list_2,list_3,list_4]                |               |
|google  | [list_1,list_2,list_3,list_5]         |               |
|tesla   | [list_1,list_2,list_3,list_4,list_5]  |               |
|facebook| [list_1,list_2,list_5]                |               |
|cisco   | [list_3]                              |               |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Problem - 
For `column3` I have to find other elements that exists in the lists from `column2` 
For e.g. - for `column1` row 1 apple I have to find with what other companies are there with apple in `[list_2,list_3,list_4]` (`column2` row 1)

My approach -

```rb
for i in range(0, len(COMPANY_DF['column2'])):
    column3_list = []    
    for company in companies:
        for j in range(0, len(COMPANY_DF['column2'].loc[i])):
            if company in COMPANY_DF['column2'].loc[i][j]:
                company.append(column3_list)
            else:
                print('Not there')
    COMPANY_DF['column3'].loc[i] = column3_list
```

I am having issue with this if statement -

```rb
if company in COMPANY_DF['column2'].loc[i][j]:
if company in COMPANY_DF['column2'].loc[i][j] is 
giving 'list_2' instead of list_2 I believe that's why it's failing.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just make a set and add all the companies in the list_2, list_3, and list_4 for 'apple' in row1?

Comment: Are the items in column 2 strings or lists of lists?  When you say it is giving 'list_2', I think they are strings.

Comment: Why would you loop over the DataFrame like that? Read the Pandas docs.

Comment: On second thought, this seems like a rather awkward way of using a DataFrame. Can you share some more context for this?

Comment: @RootTwoColumn 2 have list of lists

Comment: @AMC I have csv with 2 columns apps and servers, I want to find one app is be removed from the server what other apps get affected. I am talking in 1000s of servers

Comment: @vb_rises that's a great idea, but I have a lot of elements in column 2 some rows have more than 50, It may work I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @vb_rises I tried got stuck at the same place COMPANY_DF['column2'].loc[0][0] even though it's a list of lists when I get 1st element it coming as string, not as a list

Comment: what is the output of COMPANY_DF['column2'].loc[0]? I don't think then you have a list of lists.

Comment: You wrote in a comment on an answer _Another problem is list names are random in my program I just named continuous here for example_. Can you clarify what the program actually looks like? It's still difficult to understand what's going on.

Comment: @vb_rises 
COMPANY_DF['column2'].loc[0]
Output - ['list_2','list_3','list_4']

Comment: Then you have list of strings, NOT list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

This was my method:

```py
companies = ['apple','google','tesla','facebook','cisco']
list_1 = ['apple','google','tesla','facebook']
list_2 = ['google','tesla','facebook']
list_3 = ['apple','tesla','cisco']
list_4 = ['apple','google','tesla']
list_5 = ['google','tesla','facebook']

list_of_lists = [f'list_{i}' for i in range(1, 6)]
# will create a string named the same for each of the lists,
# so it can be added to the list of mentions later, and also evaluated.

company_mentions = []
for company in companies:
    mentions = [mention for mention in list_of_lists if company in eval(mention)]
    # a list of the lists that a particular company has been mentioned in.

    company_mentions.append(mentions)
    # will append a list of the lists that company is mentioned in.
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: you can add an `eval` around `mentions` when you append it, if you'd prefer to have the entire list instead. Whatever works best for you.

Comment: Another problem is list names are random in my program I just named continuous here for example